# ASP Net Core app recycle as ISAPI reported an unhealthy condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis-10, isapi

I'm getting a System event log entry:

```
An ISAPI reported an unhealthy condition to its worker process. Therefore, the worker process with process id of '<processID>' serving application pool '<myApp>' has requested a recycle.
```

but I am not getting anymore information other than that. What could I do to get a more detailed error message as to what "unhealthy" means?

Answer (score 1):

**Resolve**

Check an unhealthy ISAPI component:

Possible resolutions for an unhealthy ISAPI component include the following:

1. Contact the ISAPI vendor regarding the error. The vendor should have more specific knowledge about the features and behavior of the component.
2. Check the event log message for more detailed information about the error.

For more information about "Troubleshooting Unexpected Issues", you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/diagnosing-http-errors/troubleshooting-unexpected-issues).

For the verification project of this error, you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc735189(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).