# My website needs to be restarted after specific number of requests in IIS

Tags: api, asp.net-core

I have an API application and .NET Core Application which are connected to the API. My issue is after a specific number of requests, there is a message that says "The service is unavailable."

this screen appears after undefined requests:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1mik.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0Sj3.png)

I expects that the application always works unless I logout but this did not happen

Comment: Is your App pool get stopped after number of requests? there is a feature in IIS called Rapid-Fail Protection, if your app is crashing multiple times then IIS turn-off the App pool. For more information, please check [HTTP response 503 Service Unavailable from IIS](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/http-response-503-service-unavailable-from-iis-one-common/ba-p/1720007). Further, I would suggest you check the System and Application Event Viewer logs around the time you face the issue.  It could help to know more about the issue.

Comment: I made this solution but I still have an error

Comment: The document link I suggest you in my previous comment could help you find the cause of the issue. Please don't consider it as a solution. Have you check the Event Viewer logs around the time you face the issue? does it shows any errors? if yes, please share here.

Comment: "An ISAPI reported an unhealthy condition to its worker process. Therefore, the worker process with process id of '9328' serving application pool 'VCMWebService' has requested a recycle."       the previous message is shown in event viewer logs

Comment: Please note that the previous message shows only when restarting my app but when the problem happens no errors appear.

Comment: If we refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc735189(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#check-an-unhealthy-isapi-component) it suggests that you may need to contact the vendor of ISAPI to know more about the error. Ref [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65912562/asp-net-core-app-recycle-as-isapi-reported-an-unhealthy-condition)

Comment: no info about the link

Comment: I would like to know whether you are using `ISAPI` with your site hosted on the IIS?

Comment: An Internet server API (ISAPI) is a set of ready-made Windows program calls that developers can use in order create custom enhancements or extensions to ISAPI-compliant HTTP servers or web servers. As Event logs mentioned about ISAPI, I would like to know whether you are using it.

Comment: no, I am not using it